# cmd script - set does not apear to be executed

Tags: cmd, set

I am trying to get the pathname of a service into a variable in my cmd script. When it executes I get the line saying set idmsys=C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe but it does not actually set the variable. Can anyone explain why?

Here is the snippet:

```
wmic service spooler get pathname | for /f %%i in ('find /I "spool"') do set idmsys=%%i
```

If I do an echo %idmsys% afterwards the variable is blank.

Comment: When a command is piped with `| batch_command` this will instantiate a new `CMD.exe instance`... Run `for /F "tokens=1"` against `('wmic service spooler get pathname^, SystemName ^| find /I "spool"')` rather.

Comment: Worked like a champ I was not aware this would instantiate a new CMD.exe instance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run rather

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('
      wmic service spooler get pathname^, SystemName ^| find /I "spool"
  ') do set "idmsys=%%i"
```

When a command is piped with `| batch_command` this will instantiate a new `CMD.exe` instance. **Proof**:

```
==>wmic process where "CommandLine like 'wmic%' or CommandLine like 'findstr%' or CommandLine like '%cmd%'" get caption, commandline, ProcessID, ParentProcessID /value | findstr "^"

Caption=cmd.exe
CommandLine="C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
ParentProcessId=3096
ProcessId=4148

Caption=WMIC.exe
CommandLine=wmic  process where "CommandLine like 'wmic%' or CommandLine like 'findstr%' o
r CommandLine like '%cmd%'" get caption, commandline, ProcessID, ParentProcessID /value
ParentProcessId=4148
ProcessId=2084

Caption=findstr.exe
CommandLine=findstr  "^"
ParentProcessId=4148
ProcessId=4596

==>
```

Any changes made to environment in a *parallel* or even *child* `cmd` instance does not affect a *parallel* nor even *parent* one. **Proof**:

```
d:\bat>set idmsys
Environment variable idmsys not defined

d:\bat>cmd /E /V /C cd files ^& set "idmsys=!CD!" ^& set idmsys ^& pause
idmsys=d:\bat\files
Press any key to continue . . .

d:\bat>set idmsys
Environment variable idmsys not defined

d:\bat>
```